# NVD3 - how to create a simple timeline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am interested in creating a simple timeline chart in which Events are shown on the X-axis and Dates are shown on the Y-axis. I have provided a sample code below in which this may be accomplished using a multi-bar chart, but I would like for events to be represented as points instead of bars. It is also unclear to me how to properly format the dates returned. Please take a look and thanks in advance for your help and clarification

http://jsfiddle.net/acreton/4ALS7/

```
<div id="chart">
    <svg style="height:250px;"></svg>
</div>

var data = [
    {
        'key': 'Timeline',
        'values': [
            ['Event 1', 1136005200000],
            ['Event 2', 1201755600000],
            ['Event 3', 1225425600000],
            ['Event 4', 1288497600000],
            ['Event 5', 1293771600000],
            ['Event 6', 1322629200000]
        ]
    }
    ]

    var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        .margin({ top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 90 })
        .x(function (d) { return d[0]; })
        .y(function (d) { return d[1]; })
    ;

    console.log(chart.width());

    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('')
        .tickFormat(function (x) { return x.toString(); });

    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('')
        .tickFormat(function (y) { return d3.time.format('%y')(new Date(y)); });

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
```

Comment: Just as a FYI, here is a [library](http://visjs.org/#gallery) where timelines have been an important focus.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question, since your Fiddle may change. The site told you as much when you tried to post just a link to the code.

Comment: Updated with code from fiddle

Comment: Why not at least try to use the scatter plot? http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html